# Property of RWMutex in Golang

Tags: go, mutex

I was reading this page on [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem). In the Locks subsection under Synchronization section, there is a sentence about a property of RWMutex:

> For any call to l.RLock on a sync.RWMutex variable l, there is an n such that the l.RLock happens (returns) after call n to l.Unlock and the matching l.RUnlock happens before call n+1 to l.Lock.

I do understand what RWMutex is for but can't seem to relate this property to the functionalities of RWMutex. Could you help me understand this property of RWMutex?

Comment: This is the _formal_ specification of what you know about a RWMutex. Just forget about this n-stuff. It states that once you did n Unlock ops you can do an RLock followed by an RUnlock before the next Lock and that these happen in the order you expect them to.